# Is there a shorter way to make this function?

Tags: python

B. front_x Given a list of strings, return a list with the strings in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first. e.g. ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'] yields ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix'] Hint: this can be done by making 2 lists and sorting each of them before combining them.

```
def front_x(words):
  xList = []
  nonXList = []
  for word in words:
    if word[0] == 'x':
      xList.append(word)
    else:
      nonXList.append(word)
  return sorted(xList) + sorted(nonXList)
```

I'm new to python and programming in general but I feel there is a more compact way to write this code or is there a more 'pythonic' way?

also I tried to return the line:

```
return xlist.sort() + nonXList.sort()
```

but this erred out. Why did that happen?

Comment: Python has a one-liner for everything. Though not all one-liners are pythonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could sort `words` with one call to `sorted` using the `key` parameter to "teach" `sorted` how you wish the items in `words` to be ordered:

```
def front_x(words):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda word: (word[0] != 'x', word))
```

The `key` function is called once for every item in `words` and returns a proxy value by which the items in `words` is to be sorted. `tuples` such as the one returned by the `lambda` function above, are sorted in lexicographic order (according to the first item in the tuple, and according to the second to break ties).

This technique as well as others is explained in the excellent [Sorting Howto](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

---

For example,

```
print(front_x(['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']))
# ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

---

Note that if `words` contains an empty string, `word[0]` will raise an `IndexError`. In contrast `''.startswith('x')` returns `False`. 
So use `word.startswith('x')` if you wish `front_x` to handle empty strings, and use `word[0] == 'x'` if you wish to raise an exception.

Comment: for (word[0] != 'x', word) wouldn't this sort the non x words first because of word[0] !='x' as in aardvark, apple, mix? Could you explain how the statement (word[0] != 'x', word) is read and evaluated? Essentially im cunfused why it is word[0] != 'x' instead of word[0] = 'x'

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehensions

```
list =  ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
list.sort()
listA = [item for item in list if item[0] == 'x']
listB = [item for item in list if item[0] != 'x']
listC = listA + listB
```

Comment: But you shouldn't use `is` to compare values

Comment: @KEYSER It does work, but not in this case. We want to know if the first character is 'x', not any character.

Answer (score 2):

This works,and it's simple and easy to understand.

```
def front_x(words):
    xlist = [item for item in words if item[0] =='x']
    nonXList = [item for item in words if item[0] !='x']
    xlist.sort() # The .sort() method sorts a list alphabetically 
    nonXList.sort()
    Combined_Lists = xlist + nonXList
    return Combined_Lists
    #You can also comment Combined_Lists and 
    #just have return xlist + nonXList
```

Since you're new to Python,I tried to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The error for your return is because sort does not return a value, it merely modifies the list.

This seems a fairly fast way to do this, it runs in linear time, you won't get much faster than that. That being said, you could do inline code to shorten it, but it's not always more readable that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'] 
>>> sorted ([x for x in l if x.startswith('x')]) + sorted([x for x in l if not x.startswith('x')])
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return sorted([w for w in words if w[0] == 'x']) + sorted([w for w in words if w[0] != 'x'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `.sort()` is in-place. It returns `None`, and you can't do `None + None`

Since Python's sort is stable, you can also accomplish this by doing two sorts

```
>>> L = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
>>> sorted(sorted(L), key=lambda x:x[0]!='x')
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

And the in-place version

```
>>> L.sort()
>>> L.sort(key=lambda x:x[0]!='x')
>>> L
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```